# 'get' replacement that throws exception on not found?

Tags: clojure

I'd like to access values in maps and records, throwing an exception when the key isn't present.  Here's what I've tried.  Is there a better strategy?

This doesn't work because `throw` is evaluated every time:

```
(defn get-or-throw-1 [rec key]
  (get rec key (throw (Exception. "No value."))))
```

Maybe there's a simple method using a macro?  Well, this isn't it; it has same problem as the first definition, even if the evaluation of `throw` happens later:

```
(defmacro get-or-throw-2 [rec key]
  `(get ~rec ~key (throw (Exception. "No value."))))
```

This one works by letting `get` return a value that (in theory) would never be generated any other way:

```
(defn get-or-throw-3 [rec key]
  (let [not-found-thing :i_WoUlD_nEvEr_NaMe_SoMe_ThInG_tHiS_021138465079313
        value (get rec key not-found-thing)]
    (if (= value not-found-thing)
        (throw (Exception. "No value."))
        value)))
```

I don't like having to guess what keywords or symbols would never occur through other processes. (I could use `gensym` to generate the special value of `not-found-thing`, but I don't see why that would be better.  I don't have to worry about someone intentionally trying to defeat the purpose of the function by using the value of not-found-thing in a map or record.)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what the `find` function is for: `(find m k)` returns `nil` if nothing was found, or `[k v]` if a mapping from `k` to `v` was found. You can always distinguish these two, and don't need to guess at what might already be in the map. So you can write:

```
(defn strict-get [m k]
  (if-let [[k v] (find m k)]
    v
    (throw (Exception. "Just leave me alone!"))))
```

Comment: All three answers given so far are very helpful.  Both your answer, amalloy, and @noisesmith's together qualify as "the answer", in my opinion, even though @mange's was also informative.  Have to choose one, though, and yours fits my personal aesthetic a little better, even though I see the sense of noisesmith's approach.  (I knew about `find`, but it didn't occur to me to use it in the way that you suggest.)

Comment: `find` only words for maps, so this function is less general than normal `get`. That is probably not what a user of this function would expect

Answer (score 9):

This is the sort of thing that [preconditions](http://blog.fogus.me/2009/12/21/clojures-pre-and-post/) were meant for. They are built in to the language and should be used for input validation (though you can alternately use an assertion if preconditions are not flexible for a specific case).

```
user> (defn strict-get
        [place key]
        {:pre [(contains? place key)]}
        (get place key))
#'user/strict-get
user> (strict-get {:a 0 :b 1} :a)
0
user> (strict-get {:a 0 :b 1} :c)
AssertionError Assert failed: (contains? place key)  user/eval6998/fn--6999/strict-get--7000 (form-init7226451188544039940.clj:1)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use a namespace-qualified keyword, which reduces the chance of an accidental use of your keyword:

```
(defn get-or-throw [coll key]
  (let [result (get coll key ::not-found)]
    (if (= result ::not-found)
      (throw (Exception. "No value."))
      result)))
```

Alternatively, you can just use `contains?`:

```
(defn get-or-throw [coll key]
  (if (contains? coll key)
    (get coll key)
    (throw (Exception. "No value."))))
```

This should be safe as your map/record should be immutable.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the name and implementation from simulant: `getx` and `getx-in`

```
(defn getx
  "Like two-argument get, but throws an exception if the key is
   not found."
  [m k] 
  (let [e (get m k ::sentinel)]
    (if-not (= e ::sentinel)
      e 
      (throw (ex-info "Missing required key" {:map m :key k})))))

(defn getx-in
  "Like two-argument get-in, but throws an exception if the key is
   not found."
  [m ks] 
  (reduce getx m ks))
```

https://github.com/Datomic/simulant/blob/d681b2375c3e0ea13a0df3caffeb7b3d8a20c6a3/src/simulant/util.clj#L24-L37

Answer (score 2):

This function is also implemented in the [tupelo](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo) library under the name `grab`.  Note that the argument order is reversed here, seemingly intentionally: `(grab :my-key my-map)`.